# Remap the Print Screen command

Tags: shortcut-keys

If I press, `Print` on the key board, I get the command `gnome-screenshot` executed.

I would like to change it to `gnome-screenshot -a` (much more useful, select the region of the screen to copy, should be default IMHO).

I could remap the keyboard shortcut of `Print` to `gnome-screenshot -a` but when I look in the pre-defined shortcuts, I see:

[image: Keyboard shortcut]

which means that somewhere, the system configures: `Take a screenshot` -> `gnome-screenshot`. How can I change this very specific config?

**Bonus**: if the solution can be scripted, it would be better so I don't need to reconfigure on every new system install (as I keep a setup script up to date when reinstalling my system).

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The facility to take a screenshot *of an area only* is already built in with the combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScrn</kbd>. With Trusty Tahr see under:

```
System Settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> Screenshots
```

And I demonstrate this in the following screenshot:

[image]

Directions are available on this screen, at the base, to disable or modify the keys as you wish...